# Audio file switches languages during viewing

Tags: audio, video, language

I am having difficulty finding software that might help me find and eliminate any additional language tracks in a video file I am viewing.  The file info indicates there are four language tracks included in the .AVI file.

Are there any suggestions on how I might edit the .AVI file to remove all the other language tracks besides English?

Answer (score 1):

You could transcode the file using Handbrake (free and very good);

http://handbrake.fr/

This allows selection of which audio track you would like to use for the output file.